# Ignore white-space when capturing text between parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I've managed to get the text inside `(` `)` parenthesis. Also, I'm able to trim the leading whitespace but I can't get rid of the trailing whitespace.

For text  `node     (    t-vr0wkjqky55s9mlh2rtt0u301(asdad)   ) { }`

my regex `\(\s*(.*)\)` is returning 
`t-vr0wkjqky55s9mlh2rtt0u301(asdad)   /`     *(notice the trailing whitespace and ignore `/`)*.

Here's the running code https://regex101.com/r/uMfr4G/1/

And a live example of the problem:

```js
var str = "node     (    t-vr0wkjqky55s9mlh2rtt0u301(asdad)   ) { }";
var rex = /\(\s*(.*)\)/;
console.log("[" + rex.exec(str)[1] + "]");
```

Comment: If you don’t need to handle this “purely in regex” only, but in a language like JavaScript - then why not simply add a replace call that replaces white space with an empty string on the found match …? `console.log("[" + (rex.exec(str)[1]).replace(/\s/g, '') + "]");`

Comment: Try [`\(\s*(.*\S)\s*\)`](https://regex101.com/r/S6K4ft/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks it works! would you mind adding it as an answer so i can close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/\(\s*(.*\S)\s*\)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S6K4ft/1).

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `(.*\S)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (`.*`), and then any non-whitespace char (maybe, instead of `\S`, `[^)\s]` / `[^()\s]` can be a better option here to exclude matching parentheses)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `\)` -  a `)`.

Updated snippet:

```js
var str = "node     (    t-vr0wkjqky55s9mlh2rtt0u301(asdad)   ) { }";
var rex = /\(\s*(.*\S)\s*\)/;
console.log("[" + rex.exec(str)[1] + "]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `\(\s*(\S*)\s*\)`

```js
var str = "node     (    t-vr0wkjqky55s9mlh2rtt0u301(asdad)   ) { }";
var rex = /\(\s*(\S*)\s*\)/;
console.log("[" + rex.exec(str)[1] + "]");
```

Comment: it almost works could you modify it to handle with greedy aproach ie.  (    t-vr0wkjqky55s9mlh2rtt0u301  (asdad)   ) should return t-vr0wkjqky55s9mlh2rtt0u301  (asdad)